# R: Counting dates within time intervals

Tags: r, date

Assume we have data input:

```
df.in <- data.frame(event = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                    start = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-02",
                              "2015-01-02", "2015-01-03"),
                    end = c("2015-01-03", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-03",
                            "2015-01-05", "2015-01-05"))
df.in$start <- as.Date(df.in$start, "%Y-%m-%d")
df.in$end <- as.Date(df.in$end, "%Y-%m-%d")

> df.in
  event      start        end
1     1 2015-01-01 2015-01-03
2     2 2015-01-01 2015-01-04
3     3 2015-01-02 2015-01-03
4     4 2015-01-02 2015-01-05
5     5 2015-01-03 2015-01-05
```

Goal is to count date occurrences for all events (including start, excluding end). To fill out this data frame:

```
df.out <- data.frame(date = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-02", "2015-01-03", 
                              "2015-01-04", "2015-01-05"),
                     count = 0)
df.out$date <- as.Date(df.out$date, "%Y-%m-%d")
> df.out
        date count
1 2015-01-01     0
2 2015-01-02     0
3 2015-01-03     0
4 2015-01-04     0
5 2015-01-05     0
```

Conceptually it would look something like this:

```
#1 **
#2 ****
#3 ***
#4 **
#5
```

So, my current idea is a loop:

```
for(i in seq_along(df.out$date)){
  temp.df <- df.in[df.in$start <= df.out$date[i],]
  df.out$count[i] <- nrow(temp.df) - nrow(temp.df[temp.df$end <= df.out$date[i],])
}
> df.out
        date count
1 2015-01-01     2
2 2015-01-02     4
3 2015-01-03     3
4 2015-01-04     2
5 2015-01-05     0
```

It works, but I am sort of afraid that this `temp.df` that I am invoking can potentially snowball into something very large. Given that count of events can easily go into tens or even hundreds of thousands.

So my question is - can there be a more efficient way? Perhaps by using some date packages such as `lubridate` where I can somehow vectorize the whole thing?

Comment: Ah... so I got keywords wrong again for search. Apparently I was looking for "overlaps". Thanks!

Comment: Given that I'm familiar with data table package for a whole hour, these things seem somewhat sophisticated for my knowledge. However I will take your example and experiment a bit to see where it leads, thanks a lot!

Comment: I've made an edit on your answer (if you don't mind) in order to illustrate my comment.

Answer (score 2):

So I've done my research on `data.table::foverlaps()`. I'll leave my findings to whoever might find it useful as I honestly didn't really find these little things in searching similar posts.

Given that we are comparing intervals and we have interval only on `y` argument which is `df.in` in this particular case - we have to artificially make one. As in `df.out$date2 <- df.out$date` for example. Also, there is no straightforward (or I couldn't find any) way to set inclusion or exclusion of set interval endpoints. Given that we want to exclude endpoint in `df.in$end` we'll have to do it manually on the data table itself with plain simple `df.in$end <- df.in$end - 1`.

Long story short, here is a working example:

```
require(data.table)
df.out <- data.table(date = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-02", "2015-01-03", 
                              "2015-01-04", "2015-01-05"),
                     count = 0)
df.out$date <- as.Date(df.out$date, "%Y-%m-%d")

df.in <- data.table(event = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                    start = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-02",
                              "2015-01-02", "2015-01-03"),
                    end = c("2015-01-03", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-03",
                            "2015-01-05", "2015-01-05"))
df.in$start <- as.Date(df.in$start, "%Y-%m-%d")
df.in$end <- as.Date(df.in$end, "%Y-%m-%d") - 1

setkey(df.in, start, end)
df.out$date2 <- df.out$date
df.test <- foverlaps(x = df.out, y = df.in, type = "within", by.x = c("date", "date2"), by.y = c("start", "end"))
df.test$count[!is.na(df.test$event)] <- 1
aggregate(count ~ date, data = df.test, sum)

        date count
1 2015-01-01     2
2 2015-01-02     4
3 2015-01-03     3
4 2015-01-04     2
5 2015-01-05     0
```

---

Alternatively, you could do

*Data*

```
df.out <- data.table(date = as.Date(c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-02", "2015-01-03", 
                              "2015-01-04", "2015-01-05")))

df.in <- data.table(event = 1:5, 
                    start = as.Date(c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-02",
                              "2015-01-02", "2015-01-03")),
                    end = as.Date(c("2015-01-03", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-03",
                            "2015-01-05", "2015-01-05")))
```

*Solution*

```
df.out[, `:=`(start = date, end = date)]
df.in[, end := end - 1L]
setkey(df.out, start, end)
foverlaps(df.in, df.out)[, .(count = .N), by = date]
#          date count
# 1: 2015-01-01     2
# 2: 2015-01-02     4
# 3: 2015-01-03     3
# 4: 2015-01-04     2
```

*Or*, if you want to update `df.out`, you could also do

```
res <- foverlaps(df.in, df.out, which = TRUE)[, .N, by = yid]
df.out[res$yid, Count := res$N]
df.out[is.na(Count), Count := 0L]
```